# how to read mysql table records and store in javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to read data from mysql table and store the data in a javascript object to be used for display using angularJs ng-repeat.
MySql table has the following fields:
Id categoryname parentId

if parentId is 0, then its a root category, and I am trying to organize the data under javascrip object, in the root -> child hierarchy using parentId field. Can someone, please help me in this?

Comment: What back-end language are you using?

Comment: i have the api, (slim api) ready and working for reading the mysql table records; and using the angularjs factory service to access and store the data

Comment: MrUpsidedown, here is the code that I have tried so far

Comment: slim api(php)
function getRootCats()
{
 <get cats from mysql, where cat parent=0>
}

angularjs
.factory('catService', function($http){
 getCats: function(){
  return $http.post('api/roots').then(function(response){
   return response.data;
  });
 }
})

.controller('cCtrl', function(catService){
 caService.getCats().then(function(response){
  $scope.rootCats = response.data;
 });
})

html
<li ng-repeat="root in rootCats"><h2>root.catName</h2>
 <ul><li ng-repeat="child in childCats">child.catName</li></ul>
</li>

My problem is about getting the childCats of their root category?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a service to call a Serverside script e.g. written in PHP.

AngularJS Service:

```
angular.module('app.DataService',[])
.factory('$DataService', ["$http", function ($http) {

    var onlineServiceURL = 'http://www.yourserver.tld/get-data-from-mysql.php';

    this.remoteGetData = function(someID) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(onlineServiceURL, {id: someID})
            .success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data,status,headers,config);
                deferred.resolve(data, status, headers, config);
            });       
        return deferred.promise;    
    };

}]);
```

In your controller you can call it by:

```
$DataService.remoteGetData(1).then(
    function(data) {
        // now here should be your data
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

And your PHP Script does the Connection to MySQL.

http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

You might also have a look into this article:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors

Comment: Thanks Jochen for the immediate response.

Comment: the factory service and the controller are set up. I am displaying the categories as root category as the header and all its child categories, under it. Instead of accessing mysql table for every category, Wouldn't it be better to store all the records as a javascript array object of root categories and below it, its sub categories, using angular service?

Comment: When you are storing trees with parent-child logic you will have to use a recursive approach to get the data. This can be done inside the php script and the whole tree (or a part of it - if you provide another root id then 0) can be send by the service. you might want to have a look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model too.